# How to come out of exec_command in paramiko when it's going to infinite loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, paramiko

I have used a paramiko connection to a remote server and want to execute a program there.. but the program is going to infinite loop in some cases.
How do I come out of exec_command in such case and print a suitable message?

The command I'm using to execute the script is:-

```
(stdin, stdout, stderr) = client.exec_command(command)
```

Comment: how do you decide it's in the infinite loop?

Answer (score 1):

The [`exec_command`](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.4/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.exec_command) method has a `timeout=...` parameter

Set this to some value greater than the normal expected value and the `exec_command` will raise an exception (I believe `socket.timeout` from reading the docs, though I couldn't find an ssh server to test this with)

```
client.exec_command(command, timeout=120)
```

Comment: I tried this but its still not releasing handle if the cmd in the exec_command(cmd,timeout) goes to an infinite loop.It just goes to stale state and only way to come out is by keyboard interrupt.

Comment: Post more code, I just tried this and it raised out of a `.read()` call: https://i.fluffy.cc/0PKd0JHjNnmFtlDlmlwL140xcw2b2C9C.html